# array length showing more than expected

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Am fetching  some table column data from MySQL using ajax and json and needed to show these value to the  corresponding input  id tags.But its not showing the values and array length showing more than expected .expected length value is 8 but showing 101 in console . 
and array data in console

```
    [{"name":"adasdas",
      "gen":"F",
      "add":"asdasd",
      "dob":"2019-09-25",
      "ag":"25",
      "mob":"65165165",
      "tel":"1"}]
```

My **ajax request** is this

```
$('#add').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

                    var patient_no  = $('.patient_no').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'get_visit_details.php',
                        type : 'post',
                          data :{patient_no:patient_no},
                          datatype : 'json',
                        success:function(data){

                            var len = data.length;

                            console.log(len);
              console.log(data);

                  for(var i = 0;i < len; i++){
                                var pat_name    = data[i]['name'];
                                var gender      = data[i]['gen'];
                                var address     = data[i]['add'];
                                var d_birth     = data[i]['dob'];
                                var age           = data[i]['ag'];
                                var mobile      = data[i]['mob'];
                                var tele          = data[i]['tel'];

                                $('.pat_name').val(pat_name);
                                $('.gender').val(gender);
                                $('.address').val(address);
                                $('.d_birth').val(d_birth);
                                $('.age').val(age);
                                $('.tele').val(tele);
                                $('.mobile').val(mobile);

                            }
                        }
                });
          });
```

and the **php code**  is this

```
$patient_no =   $_POST['patient_no'];

$sql = "SELECT pat_name,gender,address,d_birth,age,mobile,tele,reg_no 
        FROM patient 
        WHERE reg_no = '$patient_no' ";
$result = query($sql);
confirm($result);

if($row = fetch_array($result)) {
        $pat_name   =   $row['pat_name'];
        $gender     =   $row['gender'];
        $address    =   $row['address'];
        $d_birth    =   $row['d_birth'];
        $age        =   $row['age'];
        $mobile     =   $row['mobile'];
        $tele       =   $row['tele'];
    }

        $patient_data = array();
        $patient_data[] = array("name" => $pat_name,"gen" => $gender, "add" => $address ,"dob" => $d_birth ,
                                "ag" => $age , "mob" => $mobile,"tel" => $tele);

    echo json_encode($patient_data);
```

Comment: What you have shown is the JSON representation of an array that contains _one_ single element. (That element itself then is an _object_.)

Comment: Your server side code does not even loop, so it can put at most _one_ record into your array in the first place. So why are you even _looping_ over this on the client side then? Appears to make rather little sense.

Comment: just check the value in server side first. then check client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

101 is the length of the string

```
[{"name":"adasdas","gen":"F","add":"asdasd","dob":"2019-09-25","ag":"25","mob":"65165165","tel":"1"}]
```

The expected result of this is "1" because you have 7 json objtect inside of json array

JavaScrip can't decode de Json? Try to do this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '[{"name":"adasdas","gen":"F","add":"asdasd","dob":"2019-09-25","ag":"25","mob":"65165165","tel":"1"}]' );
console.log(obj.length);
```

This must return 1

```
console.log(obj[0].name)
```

This must return "adasdas"

I test that in developer console, if not work the likely php output contains ilegal character, show the php output in "raw" (in webbrowser click on "See source code")

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the data is array object. So get the length as follows

```
var data_count = Object.keys(data).length;
console.log(data_count);
```

If you want to get length of object then use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).length
```